# SSL - Importance of OU - Domain Control Validated

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have recently setup some server scripts to automatically process SSL / renewals using the "Let's Encrypt" registrar. This has enabled us to apply SSL certificates to some of our low key clients such as blogs, who are not willing to pay for an SSL certificate. It has also the benefit of making the whole system streamlined so that we no longer have to manually renew and a pleasant reduction in initial setup time.

However one drawback which niggles me is that this type of SSL does not validate the domain, and the "OU - Domain Control Validated" flag is missing from the certificate.

I understand as to why this is, I'm just wondering where the usage cut-off of such a certificate should lies.

Should I be using a certificate with the absence of this flag on:

- Ecommerce sites
- Does this effect PCI compliance, and if so is the basic level effected?
- SEO - Would you think that there will be any SEO impact for not validating the Domain (similar to none-SSL sites).
- Do certificates which cover multiple hosts have an impact, which are now easily be combined; or should these be avoided and have multiple certificates? Such as: mysite.com, mysite.co.uk